# Delete an object in Django

Tags: python, django

I am trying to delete an object. This is the HTML, `todo` should be deleted when you Click on button (I am trying to call `delete_todo`) :-

```
<ul>
          {% for all %}


        </ul>
```

This is the views.py,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change few things in your code.
First of all change urlpattern `delete_todo` you need to add argument, which allows to determine in view what object you want to delete:

```
url(r'^(?P<todo_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.delete_todo, name='delete_todo'),
```

Then you need change `delete_todo` itself:

```
def delete_todo(request, todo_id):
    instance = get_object_or_404(Todo, pk=todo_id)
    instance.delete()
    return redirect('index')
```

Here you can use [`get_object_or_404`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404) fuction to get object with id.

And finally you need to pass url's argument to view from template:

```
<form action="{% url 'lists:delete_todo' todo_id=todo.id %}" method=post>
      <input id="submit" type="button" value="Click" />
</form>
```

Comment: Just changed it, I am clicking on the button, but nothing is happening.

Comment: I got it, It was related to CSRF verification. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add clarification on the use of the form and csrf: it's necessary in order to ensure that different users of your app can't delete content that isn't theirs.

In your template, you'll need to include the csrf tag as such:

```
  <form method="post" action={% url 'delete_todo' todo_id=todo.id %}>
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="button" id="submit" value="Delete" />
  </form>
```